# Powershell while and until loop counting

Tags: powershell, loops, while-loop

I am new to powershell and trying to learn loops but i'm currently confused and stuck trying to create a while and until loop that,Asks input from the user, Allow input until a sentinel value is reached, Count the number of times the loop went thru, print out the user input onto new lines, then print the loop number.

```
while ($UserNumber = Read-Host -Prompt "Input a number from 1 to 10" ) 
     echo "You have entered $UserNumber, now it will count until 20."
```

This is only the start and I have no idea how to continue. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*I have no idea how to continue. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.*" --> a tutorial. That isn't even valid powershell, if you'd tried to run it it would throw an error, or even just typed it into ISE it would have red squiggly lines pointing you to the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help

```
 $loopCount = 0
do{
    $answer = Read-Host "Input a number 1 - 10" 

    Write-Host "You entered $answer"

    $loopCount++

    if($answer -eq 4){
        $answered = $true
    }



} until ($answered -eq $true)

Write-Host ("Looped {0} times" -f $loopCount)
```

Comment: Please mark and answer best suited for you so someone can get credits.

Answer (score 0):

What's in your `while` (or `until`) statement needs to result in a boolean value, much like an if `statement`.

What you're likely going to want to do here is first ask the user for a number:

```
[int] $UserNumber = Read-Host -Prompt "Input a number from 1 to 10"
Write-Host "You have entered $UserNumber, now it will count until 20."
```

Note that I've specified that the $UserNumber is an integer... this is to stop PowerShell treating it as a string, which it would be default.

Then you'll want to construct a loop that runs while a certain condition is true (I'm assuming that the number is "less than 20" is what you're thinking about here.)

```
while ($UserNumber -lt 20) {
    $UserNumber += 1 # Increase the value stored in the variable by 1.
    $UserNumber
}
```

That loop will continue, incrementing that number by one (and output it) each iteration, until it reaches 20 or higher. The last time it is output, it will display "20".

Comment: Thank you for the information, this really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$num=0

$total=0

$counter=0

do 

{

$num = Read-Host " Input Number"

$total=$total + $num

$counter++

Echo "Counter : $counter and Total : $total"

}

until($total -ge 20 -or $counter -eq 10)

Write-Host "Output : $total and Number Input : $counter"
```

Results

[image]

Comment: dont be hurry with out proper formatting of the code. please write what you are trying to achieve with this piece of code. code only answers are discouraged in SO